# MySQL: ERROR 1022 (23000): Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-2b8_2'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going to implement a bookstore database. I have created the table `book`, `author`, and `publisher`. I'd like to make the following two relationships.

```
Book is written by Author.
Book is published by Publisher.
```

In order to implement these relationships, I write some SQL statements like:

```
create table book(
            ISBN varchar(30) NOT NULL,
            title varchar(30) not null,
            author varchar(30) not null,
            stock Int,
            price Int,
            category varchar(30), 
            PRIMARY KEY ( ISBN )
);

create table author(
            author_id int not null auto_increment,
            author_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
            address varchar(50) not null,
            ISBN varchar(30) not null,
            primary key (author_id)
);

alter table author add constraint ISBN foreign key (ISBN) references book (ISBN);

create table publisher(
            publisher_id int not null auto_increment,
            publisher_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
            address varchar(50) not null,
            ISBN varchar(30) not null,
            primary key (publisher_id)
);

alter table publisher add constraint ISBN foreign key (ISBN) references book (ISBN);
```

When MySQL shell executes the last `alter` statement, I get this error.

```
ERROR 1022 (23000): Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-2b8_2'
```

Originally, can't foreign key be designated two times? What's wrong with? Thank you in advance.

Comment: use some other name for last foreign key

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are getting the `duplicate key error` cause there is already a constraint named `ISBN` present in database per your first `alter` statement to `author` table

```
alter table author add constraint ISBN foreign key (ISBN) references book (ISBN);
```

Try using a different name for the constraint in `Publisher` table

```
alter table publisher add constraint ISBN1 
foreign key (ISBN) references book (ISBN);
```

Comment: I've also had this problem with MySQL 5.7.26, but being sure I didn't have any other existing key with the same name. There had previously been a key with the same name, but it had been deleted. I solved it by exporting the schema, deleting it and importing it again. I imagine it will be some MySQL problem that does not empty its caches well, despite having restarted the service even, or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

Your data structure is strange.  You should have entity tables for `Books`, `Authors`, and `Publishers`.  These would have auto-incremented ids as primary keys and additional information.  For instance, books have "titles" and "isbn" numbers.  Authors have names.  Publishers have names and addresses.

Then you want junction tables.  So, books have one or more authors (ignoring "editors" that compile chapters from other authors), and authors can write one or more books.  This suggests a `BookAuthors` table, with one row per book and per author in the book.

Books would generally have one publisher, so this is a one-to-many relationship.  You can implement this by having `PublisherId` in the `Books` table.

Answer (score 4):

Foreign key *Constraint names* in MySQL has global visibility and hence should be unique. So better adopt a naming pattern like fk_[table name]_[field name]

Answer (score 1):

try this Alter statement,

```
alter table publisher add constraint 
ISBN_publisher foreign key (ISBN) references book (ISBN);
```

Answer (score 1):

As addition to other answers, if other answers don't make it work - check that your constraint are short enough.

**Example:**  I was getting an error with these:

```
fk_test_group_has_test_group1`
fk_test_group_has_test_header1
```

but not with these (I shortened the names):

```
fk_test_group_has_group1`
fk_test_group_has_header1
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely you already have a constraint with the name ISBN in your database. Just rename the constraints if so.

Try This

> alter table publisher add constraint P_ISBN  foreign key (ISBN)
>   references book (ISBN);

Answer (score 0):

I think the message could do with being more relevant. It has nothing to do with namespace.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @randomness answer you can see a list of all your indexs in the database like that :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME,
    INDEX_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema';
```

It can help you understand in which table this index allready exist