# Cannot forward engineer this database from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL Workbench I'm trying to forward engineer a schema, but I keep getting the message:

> ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'tbl_banner_ad'

I've looked at similar problems but all the solutions say delete this or delete that but I don't want to delete something that then impacts how my database works.

From my SQL below can anyone tell me what I need to do that will get rid of this error but won't get rid of any referential integrity or anything like that:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ibn_db
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `ibn_db` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci         ;
USE `ibn_db` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ibn_db`.`tbl_users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_users` (
  `_id` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `address_building` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `address_street` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `address_city` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `address_county` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `address_postcode` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  `address_country` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `is_admin` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `phone` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `company` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `banned` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ban_reason` VARCHAR(160) NULL,
  `ban_expiry_date` DATETIME NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `salt` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `joined_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_modified_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ibn_db`.`tbl_unauthorized_users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_unauthorized_users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_unauthorized_users` (
  `_id` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `salt` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `activation_hash` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  `created_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),    
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `activation_hash_UNIQUE` (`activation_hash` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ibn_db`.`tbl_events`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_events` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_events` (
  `_id` INT ZEROFILL UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
  `start_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `end_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `created_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_modified_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `address_building` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `address_street` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `address_city` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `address_county` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `address_postcode` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  `address_country` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `image_url` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ibn_db`.`tbl_payments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_payments` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_payments` (
  `_id` INT ZEROFILL UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ibn_db`.`tbl_attendee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_attendee` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_attendee` (
  `_id` INT ZEROFILL UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `event_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `payment_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `event_id_idx` (`event_id` ASC),
  INDEX `payment_id_idx` (`payment_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_users` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `event_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`)   
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_events` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `payment_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`payment_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_payments` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ibn_db`.`tbl_banner_ad`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_banner_ad` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_banner_ad` (
  `_id` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `payment_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `width` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `height` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `payment_id_idx` (`payment_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `payment_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`payment_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_payments` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_users` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ibn_db`.`tbl_reviews`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_reviews` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_reviews` (
  `_id` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `event_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `stars` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  INDEX `event_id_idx` (`event_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_users` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION     
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `event_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_events` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ibn_db`.`tbl_login_attempts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_login_attempts` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ibn_db`.`tbl_login_attempts` (
  `_id` INT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `success` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `fail_reason` VARCHAR(160) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`),
  INDEX `user_id_idx` (`user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_users` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

EDIT: I've tried deleting the INDEX statements from tbl_banner_ads but I can't delete it because the index is part of the foreign key.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954131/mysql-error-1022-23000-cant-write-duplicate-key-in-table-sql-2b8-2 ?

Comment: It's the same problem, but it's not a duplicate question. I'm asking for help with this particular block of SQL, not his.

Comment: You still have the same issue. In the linked question, the recommendation is to change the name of the Foreign Key part of the table mentioned in the error message. In your case, that would be the `user_id` FK, which you already created in the `CREATE` of `tbl_attendees`. Likewise, the same thing happens with `payment_id`.

Comment: It just seems a little odd that MySQL Workbench didn't give me any sort of warning or notification that it wasn't valid. I didn't know foreign key names had to be unique throughout the entire database, I just thought it was per table.

Comment: Agreed. The error seems non-intuitive. But the error does apparently translate to "your constraints names need to be unique across the database schema". Also see: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,597972,601467#msg-601467

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and change the `CREATE` for tbl_banner_ad. Change this part:

```
   CONSTRAINT `payment_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`payment_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_payments` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_users` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

to:

```
  CONSTRAINT `payment_id1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`payment_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_payments` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `ibn_db`.`tbl_users` (`_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

(Alternatively, you could name the constraints to reflect both the parent and child tablenames as well as the columnn-name. I.e. `tbl_payment_tbl_banner_ad_payment_id`.