# Why I obtain this error message trying to add a FK? #23000Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-482_1ede'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, rdbms

I am not so into database and I am finding some problem trying to add a FK (using an IDE) into a **MySql** database.

After that I add the FK I obtain the following error message:

```
#23000Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-482_1ede'
while executing:
ALTER TABLE Localization ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Localization_Country FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
  REFERENCES Country (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION 
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

The problem is that I have not this FK (I had it in the past but I removed the entire Localization table and I recreate it).

Why am I obtaining this error message? How can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23954131/mysql-error-1022-23000-cant-write-duplicate-key-in-table-sql-2b8-2/23954287, try changing the fk name

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key generally must reference keys in the master table which have *unique* data. Otherwise, the database system would have no chance to know which row in the slave table belongs to which row in the master table.

So it looks like you have the same `id` in your master table (`Country`) multiple times. You will need to resolve this situation before you can add that foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself.
The problem was that I have another table that contains a constraint with the same name and it seems that I can't have multiple constraints with the same name on different tables